# How to fill in column by referencing to another Table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, 'test' and 'test_2'

First table is 'test' with columns 'TagID' and 'MachineID'
Here I make the link between 'TagID' and 'MachineID'

```
TagID | MachineID
1332  | 13
1544  | 86
1789  | 75
```

Second table is 'test_2' with colums 'TagID','MachineID' and 'Value'
In this Table I Log data into column 'TagID' and 'Value'

```
TagID | MachineID | Value
1789  | NULL      | 35
1332  | NULL      | 41
1544  | NULL      | 50
```

Is it possible to automatically fill in column 'MachineID' in table 'test_2' with the corresponding TagID from Table 'test' when i continuously log data in 'test_2' ?

I could do it with the commmand

```
   ALTER TABLE test_2
   ALTER  MachineID AS (CASE WHEN TagID = 1332 THEN 13 WHEN TagID 
   = 1544 THEN 75.....END)
```

But I have 899 different TagID's so this would take a lot of time.

Comment: N.B. `ALTER` is a command for changing the table structure, not adding or changing data. I suggest you maybe study SQL commands, and also relational database design principles, in more detail before you create a flawed design which then causes you to tie yourself in knots later.

Comment: Yes the ALTER MachineID needs to be ADD MachineID sorry

Comment: Ok but my point was that you can only create an empty column using alter/add. You can't insert the data in the same command, which is what your code seems to be attempting. You'd need a separate insert or update statement. But anyway it's all unnecessary - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this. Just log the tags and values. Then when you need to view the data, use a `SELECT` with an `INNER JOIN` to join from test_2 to test using the tagID as the common field. Then you can include MachineID in the result whenever you need to look at it.

e.g.

```
SELECT 
  test_2.TagID, test.MachineID, test_2.Value 
FROM test_2 
  INNER JOIN test_2.TagID ON test.tagID
```

There's no point in duplicating the data in both tables - and indeed, doing so goes against one of the key concepts of relational databases.

Comment: This is true but I need both TagID and MachineID in every table of my database.
The 'test' table is only for testing, The real table called ‘PLCTag’ has both TagID and MachineID plus some more columns but those are irrelevant to my problem.  I want the ‘PLCTag’ table to be the primary table where I can add/change data. 

But with my logging program I  can only choose to log either TagID or MachineID not both.
The Reason I need both TagID and MachineID in all tables is because they get copied to Filemaker and for this to work I need both TagID and MachineID in the same table.

Comment: how are the tables being copied to FileMaker exactly? You know, I don't know how your process is working, but you could perhaps make my code above (or a version which joins to your PLCTag table instead) into a View, and then have FileMaker read the data from that view instead of direct from the table. Then it would get the necessary information, without you having to de-normalise your database. You might also want to consider whether the data structure on the FileMaker side is optimal as well. Is it intended just to mirror your MySQL database, or what?

Comment: How the tables are getting copied I have to ask my colleague but I know that he uses them to make charts of the different values like temperature, flow, ... of all the Machines. These chart are live data so I do not think a copy of a view is possible.

Comment: If he's copying tables, then copying the result of a view is no different at all. You still get a set of query results. That will not make it any less "live". Every time you execute a view, you get the latest data returned by the query stored in the view. A view is a stored _query_, not a stored _result_. In any case, the charts will only be "live" as of the last time the data was copied from mysql to filemaker. And unless you want to put a heavy load on both servers, I'm guessing that doesn't happen too frequently. Certainly not real-time, anyway.

Comment: Maybe copy is not the right word, more like a shadow table when data is logged in the MySQL table, FileMaker creates the same data in its shadow table. These shadow tables are used to update the charts every couple seconds.

Comment: I just looked this up. It seems FileMaker does this by means of maintaining an ODBC connection to the MySQL server. So the FileMaker developer selects a server, connects to it, and then decides which items from the remote database it wants to synchronise. Using ODBC it's perfectly possible to select either tables or views as the data source, it doesn't matter (because basically the end result is the same - a set of data in rows and columns).

Comment: In fact I found this [FileMaker documentation](https://www.filemaker.com/downloads/documentation/techbrief_intro_ess.pdf) which encourages using a View instead of a table, as a way to ensure only fields and rows which are absolutely required in FileMaker are selected - this improves performance by keeping network traffic to a minimum.

Comment: See page 8 of that document where it says `A common means of accomplishing all three of these goals is to define a database
view within the SQL database. A view can be thought of as a sort of virtual table,
with its own permissions. A view can combine data from several SQL tables, and
limit the number of columns (fields) and records returned.`. So I'd say that using a view would actually be the optimal solution here.

Comment: Interesting but do these virtual tables automatically get updated when new data is logged to the original table or does somebody have to constantly re-execute a query to get these virtual tables. For example, I have a table ‘Temperature’ with ‘TagID’ , ‘Value’ and ‘Time’ as its columns, If I make a view where I can see the ‘Temperature’ Table plus the corresponding ‘MachineID’ from ‘PLCTag’.
When I log new data (after making the view) in ‘Temperature’ does the Virtual table include this new data or does somebody need to make another virtual Table.

Comment: As I understand it, a shadow table is updated whenever someone visits a screen in filemaker which uses data from it. At that moment, FileMaker requests the latest version of the data from the MySQL server and stores it in its "shadow" table. It then uses the shadow data to display the relevant info on screen. So in other words, it's done on-demand. That would apply equally to a table or a view being the source of the data.

Comment: If in the meantime you added new data into MySQL while that particular filemaker screen is open, you'd have to close that screen in filemaker and re-open it, or otherwise cause it to refresh from its data source (which, being a shadow table, will in turn refresh itself from MySQL), to see the latest data.

Comment: I just had a quick word with my colleague and apparently FileMaker has its own script where I think the shadow table is automatically refreshed after x couple of seconds and this script also makes the charts. But this script does not use views from MySQL so if I want to make use of views, the script needs to be rewritten. I think this is also why  I needed TagID and MachineID in every Table.

Comment: "But this script does not use views from MySQL"...not according to the filemaker doc I linked you to...unless your colleague has written some custom script - but that seems unnecessary since it appears FileMaker supports this functionality already. It should be possible to choose either a table or a view as the source of the data for any given shadow table. After that, the process is identical.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will look into the use of views, but to be sure I would like to have the solution to the original question to fill in ‘’MachineID without the use of a view table (If that is possible), so I have at least that working. Then I can check if the use of views will change the working of the script in some way, because I do not know if the script is custom or not.

Comment: Can't your colleague already show you how he makes the shadow tables? I'd have thought it would be the work of just a few minutes to figure out if you can select a view instead (you might have to grant the right permissions before he can see it). But anyway, if you really want to mangle your data structure in the meantime then you could potentially consider creating a Trigger, which runs after each row is inserted, fetches the relevant machine ID from the other table and updates the newly created row with the retrieved value